# Elasticsearch funtion score sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I use `function_score` query with sorting, Right now if I remove the `sort` then my query returns the correct results, it will `boost`the companies with an companyId of 158.

But of i add the sort then it ignores the boosting.

Makes sense why its happening just don't know how to fix it. I tried looking into `script_score` but cant get the filter term in script

```
"script_score": {
            "script": "_score * how to get 158?"
          }


...,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "companyId": [
                158
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "companyGroupId": [
                  1595
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "lastName.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE** 
Is something like below possible?

```
         "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "companyId": 158
                    }
                  },
                  "script_score" : {
                       "script" : "doc['companyId'].value == 158 ? 4 : 0",
                   }
                }
              ],
-- Combining it with an sort--
    "sort": [
        {
          "lastName.keyword": {
            "order": "asc"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to sort and compute scores, you will need to enable "Track Scores" as shown **[here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_track_scores)**.

By default, elasticsearch will not compute scores when sorting.

Comment: Added the "Track Scores" made no difference to my result set

Comment: Managed to get it to work, turns out i forgot to add the _score as part of my sorting